# how to handle the badge and notification sound after receiving push notification?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I implement **Firebase** push notifications in my app. I can get the alert message that I sent from **Firebase** console, but it's just the alert, no sound, no badge.

So I think I have to handle the badge and the sound by myself using `import UserNotifications`, so how do I do that?

Here is the code I use to implement push notifications:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, MessagingDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FirebaseApp.configure()


        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken
        print("FCM token: \(token ?? "")")
        return true
    }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String){
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

    }
}
```